# Why Tomcat works fine when I put a .jsp but with a .html doesn't works?

Tags: java, html, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm working with eclipse and I created a project, I put a test.html and  test.jsp file in the root folder. In the URL of the Google Chrome I put this:

http://localhost:8080/project/test.html Error 404

http://localhost:8080/project/test.jsp Works (hello world!)

What is happening?

Comment: Have you verified that test.html actually exists in the file system? Make sure you save all your files in eclipse before publishing. Also if you just added the file, with eclipse sometimes you have to restart the server after publishing, although usually that process is automatic.

Comment: I restarted.. doesn't works

Comment: If it's a dynamic web project, then both test.html and test.jsp should be accessed normally if put directly under WebContent.

Comment: It really sounds to me like some sort of deployment glitch. WebContent is the right place to put it. Without more info about your setup, the context, etc. it's hard to say. It's possible you don't have something configured correctly, or perhaps confused a few things. You're using the tomcat install that's built into eclipse, rather than a standalone tomcat install, correct?

Comment: You should be able to check where your files are ending up at <Your Eclipse Workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps

Comment: @JasonC I'm using apache tomcat 8.5, downloaded, I created the Tomcat Server in Tomcat 8.5 .. and runned it

Comment: @AlessandroScarlatti This is the folder: C:\JavaProyects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\project\app

Comment: Any warnings or errors in the Issues view of eclipse? Any warning icons in the project tree? What about the server console output, any errors printed there when the server starts?

Comment: Yes there is a red [X] at the top (project) .. I'll check...

Comment: @JasonC Faceted Project Problem - Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Double check if your *test.html* exists under this path: 
***"Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\project"***

If exists, then it should be accessed normally, if not then you have to clean/build your application correctly or even try to restart eclipse.

Comment: That's there: C:\JavaProyects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.co‌​re\tmp0\wtpwebapps\p‌​roject\app

Answer (score 0):

Based on your follow-up comments about the custom Tomcat install and the project error message, it sounds like you either don't have Eclipse properly configured to use your Tomcat server, or you don't have your project associated with the Tomcat server you've set up, and so perhaps your changes arent being deployed properly. See if that issue has a quick fix suggestion (right click it) or go through your project settings and verify your selected server runtime. Sorry on phone can't give specific instructions.